# Calculation of portfolio beta (CAPM)

Tags: capm, beta, standard-deviation

Let the market risk be $\sigma_m=28\%$. A portfolio consists of four stocks, all with the same weight ($w_i=0.25$ for all $i$). We also know that $\sigma_a=18\%,\sigma_b=36\%,\sigma_c=22\%,\sigma_d=17\%$ where $\sigma_i$ is the standard deviation of stock $i$ and the portfolio's risk is $\sigma_p=24\%$

Calculate the portfolio beta ?

This is a multiple choice question with choices:(A) 0.71 (B) 0.74 (C) 0.77 (D) 0.79 (E) 0.82

I tried using the formulas $\sigma_p^2=\beta_p^2\sigma_m^2+\sum_{i=1}^n{w_i^2\sigma_{\epsilon,i}^2}$ and $\sigma_i^2=\beta_i^2\sigma_m^2+\sigma_{\epsilon,i}^2$ but i get stuck because I know neither the individual betas nor the error terms' variances.

Am I missing something or is the given data insufficient? Any tips?

Comment: Hi: where you wrote $\sigma^2_{\epsilon,i}$ are actually the individual stock variances so $\sigma_a, \sigma_b$ etc. So you have those. You also have $\sigma_m$ and the $w_i$. That leaves $\beta_p$ and $\sigma_p$. But you have $\sigma_p$. So, you have everything except $\beta_p$ which allows you to solve for it.

Comment: Now that makes sense, I get answer B "replacing" the stock variances with the error variances. I guess the question was just badly worded. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi: Yes, the stock variances are error variances under CAPM because $\beta$ explains the stock's returns and what's left over ( not explained ) is the stock's ( idiosyncratic or specific or residual ) variance.  There are many terms used but they all mean the same thing. It is  an assumption in CAPM that a stock's return is explained just by it's $\beta$.